# Ayuda para mejorar ejercicio de JavaScript

Tags: javascript, funciones, variables-globales

Me han pedido este ejercicio:

Hacer un programa JavaScript que muestre cuántos números pares hay entre 2 números dados y su suma. Y lo mismo para los impares. Sacar los resultados en una tabla. Realizarlo con 2 funciones diferentes para pares e impares y ver lo que se obtiene cuando los números dados son 10 y 100.

El programa funciona, pero no quiero usar las variables globales ya que así se pierde la esencia de poner tantas funciones. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme?

```js
function PideNumero(){
 for (;;){
  numero=prompt("Escribe un numero");
  numero=parseInt(numero);
  if(isNaN(numero)==0) 
   return numero;
  alert("no es un numero");
 }
}

function OrdenarDosNumeros(num1,num2){
 if (num1<num2){
  return[numero1,numero2];
 }
 else if (num1>num2){
  numaux=numero1;
  numero1=numero2;
  numero2=numaux;
 }
}

function CuentaPares(num1,num2){
 sumapares=0;
 pares=0;
 for (i=num1+1;i<num2;i++){
  if ((i%2)==0) {
   pares++;
   sumapares=sumapares+i;
  }
 }
}

function CuentaImpares(num1,num2){
 sumaimpares=0;
 impares=0;
 for (i=num1+1;i<num2;i++){
  if ((i%2)==1) 
   impares++;
  sumaimpares=sumaimpares+i;
 }
}

numero1=PideNumero();
numero2=PideNumero();
OrdenarDosNumeros(numero1,numero2);
CuentaPares(numero1,numero2);
CuentaImpares(numero1,numero2);
document.write(pares+" pares que suman "+sumapares+" y "+impares+" impares que suman "+sumaimpares);
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te puede interesar usar las variables let. Estas variables son de ámbito local.
Un ejemplo de declaración puede ser este:

```
let numero1=PideNumero();
let numero2=PideNumero();
```

Para más información, puedes ver esta documentación:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_let.asp

Comment: Gracias por responder tan pronto, no se si no te estoy entendiendo bien, pero creo que no es lo que busco. Lo que quiero es que cada función me devuelva (imagino que con return) tanto el resultado de la suma como el numero de pares/impares para no estar modificando las variables globales. un saludo!

Comment: Disculpa, no te había entendido yo. Y no te vale con un return normal y corriente? Si tienes un return en cada función, simplemente haciendo let a = funcion() te debe asignar en a el valor devuelto. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: pues me acabo de dar cuenta de que en la función ordenar números lo he puesto cuando ya están ordenados y no da problemas (creo que porque estoy usando las variables globales), pero cuando lo intenté donde no están ordenados con las variables de la funcion me devolvía 0 o undefined

Comment: Imagino que es porque tienes el return solo cuando se cumple la condición if(num1 < num2)